# VBA Excel how can I define a set of columns using numbers?

Tags: excel, vba

Some of us have proposed great simple ways to define a set of columns in 
Excel VBA, such as:

```
.Union(Columns("a"), Columns("b"), Columns("d"))
```

Those examples are using letters to refer to those columns. 
I need to refer to my columns using numbers, such as in:

```
.Union(Columns(2), Columns(7), Columns(23)).
```

The later works great but what if I need to refer to columns using a range of columns such as in:

```
.Union(columns(2), columns(7), columns(9 to 23))
```

The idea being that I would not have to define the .Union with each column separately, which, in the present example would necessitate 17 columns(x) listing.

Not an elegant code. Furthermore, I need to use numbers because the column numbers are determined programmatically and are changing during execution.

Thanks for your input. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use RANGE():

```
.Union(.columns(2), .columns(7), .Range(.columns(9), .columns(23)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`set MyRange = worksheets("mySheet").range( columns(1), columns(5) )`  works pretty well.
It actually select a range of columns from column 1 to column 5.
Further to that I can then use the Union to join other single columns.